# Where greater than integer - Waterline/Sails/Mongo

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to do a multiple where statement in Sails with Mongo, but I'm not having any such luck

```
    var start = moment().subtract(30, 'days').unix();
    var end = moment().unix();

    console.log(start, end)

    Measurement.find()
    .where({
        user: jwt.decoded.id,
        and: [
          { timestamp: { ">=": start }},
          { timestamp: { "<=": end }}
        ],
    })
    .sort('timestamp DESC')
    .then((results) => {
        return res.view('dashboard', {title: 'MMOL', data: results, tab: 'dashboard', code: 90})
    })
```

As an example, my start time is 1507410695 and my end time is 1510006295.

In my Collection, I have about 40 records that fall between these dates, and they are structured like so:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a0083aa25b9c9bb37b5fc5d"
    },
    "timestamp": 1509916500,
    "blood": 9,
    "carb": 20,
    "calorie": 230,
    "insulin": 2,
    "notes": null,
    "user": {
        "$oid": "59fcced3c40317c657878b5c"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2017-11-06T15:45:46.572Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2017-11-06T22:05:35.270Z"
    }
}
```

I am unable to get any results at all.  From what I can tell, I am doing this correctly. If I remove the and statement, I get all of the results without an issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the records that fall within those dates also match the same user id?

Comment: Absolutely.  If I remove the and statement, then all the records show.  if I run a query in mongo that is just { timestamp: 1509916500} it shows up.

Comment: I've also just ran a query in Node through sails to put timestamp: 1509916500 in the where section and it returned the result

Comment: How about if you try the following: ```user: jwt.decoded.id,
     timestamp: {
        '>=' : start,
        '<=' : end
     }```

Comment: Heh... That worked just fine. I always thought you had to encase multiple where statements within an and array..

Comment: Nice, I just updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `and`, you can just use

```
user: jwt.decoded.id, 
timestamp: { 
   '>=' : start, 
   '<=' : end 
}
```